# Why are unaccepted answers counting as different rep changes in user profile?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, reputation-history, unaccepted-answer

I recently answered a question and the OP picked my post as the accepted answer. A few days later, some more users had posted and my answer wasn't the best anymore, so the OP rightfully removed their acceptance vote and gave it to a more suitable answer.

The changes on my profile appear as a positive change on one day, and as a negative change on a later day (See below). I was wondering why was that design decision made and why don't those cases nullify the original reputation change instead of having it be 2 distinct ones?

**Example rep graph with actual design:**

[image: Rep changes]

If the user who accepted your answer unaccepted it later, doesn't it mean that your answer either wasn't really the answer they were looking for or wasn't the most suitable one to begin with? I'm sure there are pros and cons for both the actual design and how I think it could be (removing the original positive reputation change) so I'm really curious to know what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting history would be confusing and hard to reason about. You did have an answer accepted during that period and your history reflects what actually happened. Your answer really was the most helpful for a while till things changed and it wasn't.

Let's say for instance that answer put you over some permission threshold allowing you to perform some new action, let's imagine that was reviewing say. You go wild for a while reviewing. If we then nullify your rep change we're not going to go back and undo all those review actions too and we do want people to see that you were entitled to perform those reviews at that time even if that's no longer the case today.

Basically you can't change the past, what's done is done.

Comment: I like the permissions argument. Could you expand your answer on why you think it'd be confusing / hard to reason about ? What about a different color for neutralized rep change paired with a date telling when the negative part happened ? If no deeper reasoning is needed then so be it but I'd rather understand the full implications of both ways.

Comment: I thought I already did. If someone currently has insufficient rep to do something we can figure out that they had sufficient rep in the past rather than that there's some bug that the developers need to fix. Having to scroll back potentially years to figure that out in the case that someone's set of illegal sockpuppets were deleted for instance would be tedious.

Comment: Hmmm, I might be understanding something wrong there; are the devs really looking at the charts for such bugs ? I feel a query for user `x`'s rep at time `t` would instantly tell if the user had enough of it. The graphical aspect of it and the backend for admin actions don't have to be the same, do they ? Or are you saying that it lets the community report such bugs better ? (I feel like nobody would find such a bug by looking at the graphs though)

Comment: Us ordinary users who far outnumber the devs and moderators do the checking and lots of other free testing and bug reporting for Stack Overflow too. As to graphics and backend being different that would be another source of confusion with no obvious advantage.

Comment: Fair enough; I do believe it makes more sense logically to have the change nullified, but I didn't know it had so much to do with bug reporting and such important things.